# Why I can't parse a SimpleDateFormat with pattern "MMMMM dd" in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, date

I need to parse a string like "February 12, 1981" as a Date. I use [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). But if I do:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy").parse("February 12, 1981")
```

I get java.text.ParseException.

I tried to reduce it to see where the problem is. First:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM").parse("February")
```

works. Then:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd").parse("February 12")
```

doesn't work anymore. Anyone know why? I also tried `new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM' 'dd")`.

I'm using JRE 1.6.0_06.

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of JDK/JRE are you using?

This works fine for me with 1.4.2_14, 1.5.0_16, and 1.6.0_07:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
Date parsed = df.parse("February 12, 1981");
System.out.println(parsed);
```

output:

> Thu Feb 12 00:00:00 EST 1981

Comment: Thanks! It turns out in 1.6.0_06 it doesn't work. I ask a friend who has 1.6.0_10 to try it and it worked. So it must have been a bug fixed in 1.6.0_07. :-)

Comment: I don't see it listed under the list of bugfixes in 1.6.0_07, but hey as long as it works... http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/ReleaseNotes.html#160_07

Comment: Grrr... I just found out SimpleDateFormat parses localized dates, and my computer locale is, don't know why, Spanish, even though everything in the screen is in English.

Comment: You might want to update the original question to include the actual fix (your incorrect locale setting).