# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)

Tags: java, android, date, datetime-parsing, unparseable

I have problem with `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
SimpleDateFormat dtfmt=new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
Date dt=dtfmt.parse(deptdt);
```

In Android Emulator works fine but in phone I have this error:

> W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "24 Oct 2016 7:31 pm" (at offset 3)
>   W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)

Any solution?

Answer (score 6):

### Always specify a `Locale` with a `SimpleDateFormat`, and a `DateTimeFormatter` for custom formats.

Since the given date-time is in English, you should use `Locale.ENGLISH` with your date-time parser; otherwise, the parsing will fail in a system (computer, phone etc.) that is using a non-English type of locale.

Also, note that the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working on an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String strDateTime = "24 Oct 2016 7:31 pm";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()             // For case-insensitive (e.g. am, Am, AM) parsing 
                .appendPattern("d MMM uuuu h:m a")  // Pattern conforming to the date-time string
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);       // Locale
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-10-24T19:31
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/B1rNDn)

By default, [`DateTimeFormatter#ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) uses the [default FORMAT locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault-java.util.Locale.Category-) which the JVM sets during startup based on the host environment. Same is the case with [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String)). I have tried to illustrate the problem through the following demo:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String strDateTime = "24 Oct 2016 7:31 pm";           
        DateTimeFormatter dtfWithDefaultLocale = null;          

        System.out.println("JVM's Locale: " + Locale.getDefault());
        // Using DateTimeFormatter with the default Locale
        dtfWithDefaultLocale = getDateTimeFormatterWithDefaultLocale();
        System.out.println("DateTimeFormatter's Locale: " + dtfWithDefaultLocale.getLocale());
        System.out.println(
                "Parsed with JVM's default locale: " + LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfWithDefaultLocale));

        // Setting the JVM's default locale to Locale.FRANCE
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);
        
        // Using DateTimeFormatter with Locale.ENGLISH explicitly (recommended)
        DateTimeFormatter dtfWithEnglishLocale = getDateTimeFormatterWithEnglishLocale();
        System.out.println("JVM's Locale: " + Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println("DateTimeFormatter's Locale: " + dtfWithEnglishLocale.getLocale());
        LocalDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfWithEnglishLocale);
        System.out.println("Parsed with Locale.ENGLISH: " + zdt);

        
        System.out.println("JVM's Locale: " + Locale.getDefault());
        // Using DateTimeFormatter with the default Locale
        dtfWithDefaultLocale = getDateTimeFormatterWithDefaultLocale();
        System.out.println("DateTimeFormatter's Locale: " + dtfWithDefaultLocale.getLocale());
        System.out.println(
                "Parsed with JVM's default locale: " + LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfWithDefaultLocale));
    }
    
    static DateTimeFormatter getDateTimeFormatterWithDefaultLocale() {
        return new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()             
                .appendPattern("d MMM uuuu h:m a") 
                .toFormatter(); // Using default Locale
    }
    
    static DateTimeFormatter getDateTimeFormatterWithEnglishLocale() {
        return new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()             
                .appendPattern("d MMM uuuu h:m a") 
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH); // Using Locale.ENGLISH
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
JVM's Locale: en_GB
DateTimeFormatter's Locale: en_GB
Parsed with JVM's default locale: 2016-10-24T19:31
JVM's Locale: fr_FR
DateTimeFormatter's Locale: en
Parsed with Locale.ENGLISH: 2016-10-24T19:31
JVM's Locale: fr_FR
DateTimeFormatter's Locale: fr_FR
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '24 Oct 2016 7:31 pm' could not be parsed at index 3
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/esJOmH)

---

**The following demo, using `SimpleDateFormat`, is just for the sake of completeness:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final String strDateTime = "24 Oct 2016 7:31 pm";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy h:m a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Mon Oct 24 19:31:00 BST 2016
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/1kDonH)

---

<sub>**Note**: [Predefined Formatters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) do not accept Locale (i.e. they work with the system's `Locale`).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Your `deptdt` contains `Oct` which looks like an English month name.
But your `Locale.getDefault()` probably gives a non-english locale.
Replace it by `Locale.ENGLISH` or `Locale.US`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dtfmt=new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date dt=dtfmt.parse(deptdt);
```

Answer (score 2):

It probably happens because the phone's default locale is not English, and the month name in your input is (`Oct`).

The solution is to explicity use the English locale:

```
SimpleDateFormat dtfmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date dt = dtfmt.parse("24 Oct 2016 7:31 pm");
```

---

Instead of directly working with `SimpleDateFormat` (as this old API has [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api)), you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. To use it in **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The main classes to be used are `org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime` (it seems the best choice, as you have date and time fields in your input) and `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter` (to parse the input). I also use `java.util.Locale` class to make sure it parse the month names in English, and the `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to make sure it parses `pm` (make it case insensitive, as the default is `PM`):

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // case insensitive to parse "pm"
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    // pattern
    .appendPattern("dd MMM yyyy h:mm a")
    // use English locale to parse month name (Oct)
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
// parse input
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("24 Oct 2016 7:31 pm", fmt);
System.out.println(dt); // 2016-10-24T19:31
```

The output will be:

> 2016-10-24T19:31

If you need to convert this to a `java.util.Date`, you can use the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class. But you also need to know what timezone will be used to convert this. In the example below, I'm using "UTC":

```
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(dt.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
```

To change to a different zone, you can do:

```
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(dt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).toInstant());
```

Note that the API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231). To find the timezone that better suits each region, use the `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` method and check which one fits best for your use cases.

**PS:** the last example above (`dt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))`) will create the date/time `2016-10-24T19:31` in London timezone. But if what you want is `2016-10-24T19:31` in UTC, then convert it to another timezone, then you should do:

```
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(dt
    // first convert it to UTC
    .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    // then convert to LondonTimezone
    .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).toInstant());
```