# How do you parse date String in the form "Nov 17, 2016 7:26:57 PM" into Date?

Tags: java, string, date, parsing

I tried the following pattern with `new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse("Nov 17, 2016 7:26:57 PM")` but none of them work:

```
MMM d, yyyy h:m:s a
MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a
MMM dd, yyyy h:m:s a
```

The only way I can parse this string successfully is to use `new Date("Nov 17, 2016 7:26:57 PM")` but this call is obsolete. It is said to be replaced by `DateFormat.parse()` according to the API documentation but actually it failed to parse the same string when I call `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().parse("Nov 17, 2016 7:26:57 PM")`. So how should I parse this string correctly other than using `new Date()`?

Comment: `MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a` should work, if you specify an English locale. If it doesn't, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes an English locale solve the problem! Thanks!

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

- Make sure the pattern is right
- Specify the right locale

In this case, you want an English locale for English month names:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Note that this pattern isn't any of the ones you specified:

- We need `d` because presumably you'd get "Nov 5" rather than "Nov 05"
- We need `h` because you're getting a 12-hour hour, with only a single digit for values under 10
- We need `mm` and `ss` because you'll get double digits for minutes and seconds

Comment: I've tested that all three patterns can parse correctly after I specify the locale...

Comment: @ivanhjc: They will all parse invalid data though, e.g. "23:00:00 AM", "7:5:6PM". The pattern I've provided is a much better one. It's definitely worth paying very close attention to this sort of thing.

Answer (score -1):

code:

```
public void testDate() throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a");
        Date d1 = sdf.parse("Nov 17, 2016 7:26:57 PM");
        System.out.println(d1);
        return;
    }
```

output:

```
Thu Nov 17 19:26:57 CET 2016
```

Comment: You're still using the system default locale.

Comment: This same code doesn't work for me because the locale is not specified. It works only if I add the an English locale into the constructor.