# How to format a ZonedDateTime to a String?

Tags: java, string, java-time, zoneddatetime

I want to convert a `ZonedDateTime` to a `String` in the format of `("dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm")`. I know this is possible in Joda-Time other types, just using their `toString("dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm")`....But this doesn't work with `ZonedDateTime.toString()`.

## **How can I format a `ZonedDateTime` to a `String`?**

---

EDIT:

I tried to print the time in another timezone and the result appears to be the same always:

```
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZoneId la = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
ZonedDateTime date2 = date.of(date.toLocalDateTime(), la);

// 24/02/2017 - 04:53
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm").format(date));
// same result as the previous one
// 24/02/2017 - 04:53
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm").format(date2));
```

And I am not in the same timezone as Los Angeles.

---

EDIT 2:

Found how to change the timezones:

```
// Change this:
ZonedDateTime date2 = date.of(date.toLocalDateTime(), la); // incorrect!
// To this:
ZonedDateTime date2 = date.withZoneSameInstant(la);
```

Comment: are you using jdk8 java.time.ZonedDateTime ?

Comment: Yes, I think so...

Comment: Use format() method from ZonedDateTime type

Comment: Using the symbol "h" (small letter) is a heavy mistake. Either use it in combination with am/pm because it is a 12-hour-field, or use the symbol "H" (capital letter) for 24-hour-field.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Here there is an example

```
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now();

System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm").format(date));
```

Comment: Thanks! this works!...now I just need to figure how to change between one timezone to another and print it accordingly ...

Comment: Is it just my impression but this will always print the `ZonedDateTime` ignoring the time zone it defined?

Comment: Never mind, I found out I need to use `ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant()`...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks for above. Here it is in scala where localDateTime.now always Zulu/UTC time.

```scala
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId

val ny = ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
val utc = ZoneId.of("UTC")
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.now.atZone(utc)

val nyTime = DateTimeFormatter.
      ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm z").
      format(dateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ny))
```

Answer (score 2):

### The format `dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm` does not make sense

The format `dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm` does not make sense because of missing `a` which gives it a meaning. Note that `h` represents *clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)* and `a` represents *am-pm-of-day* i.e. without `a`, the hour returned by `h` will be ambiguous e.g. without `a`, `h` will not differentiate between 9:00 am and 9:00 pm.

Therefore, use `H` which represents *hour-of-day (0-23)* or use **`h` with `a`**.

Also, always use `Locale` with the formatter because [Date-Time parsing/formatting API is Locale-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
ZonedDateTime zdt9Am = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.of(9, 0), zoneId);
ZonedDateTime zdt9Pm = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.of(21, 0), zoneId);

DateTimeFormatter ambiguousFormatter = 
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
String ambiguosDtStr1 = zdt9Am.format(ambiguousFormatter);
String ambiguosDtStr2 = zdt9Pm.format(ambiguousFormatter);
System.out.println(ambiguosDtStr1); // 08/10/2022 - 09:00
System.out.println(ambiguosDtStr2); // 08/10/2022 - 09:00

DateTimeFormatter correctAmPmFormatter = 
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(zdt9Am.format(correctAmPmFormatter)); // 08/10/2022 - 09:00 AM
System.out.println(zdt9Pm.format(correctAmPmFormatter)); // 08/10/2022 - 09:00 PM

DateTimeFormatter correct24HourFormatter = 
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(zdt9Am.format(correct24HourFormatter)); // 08/10/2022 - 09:00
System.out.println(zdt9Pm.format(correct24HourFormatter)); // 08/10/2022 - 21:00
```

Check [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) documentation to learn more about it.

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.