# Java 8 ZonedDateTime format date

Tags: java, java-time

I am writing a code to get current date of British Summer Time.
I am stuck in converting the date in desired format using below code.

```
ZoneId zid = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");      
ZonedDateTime lt = ZonedDateTime.now(zid); 


// create a formatter
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
// apply format()
String value = lt.format(formatter);

System.out.println("value ="+value);
```

I am getting the output as value =2020-06-01+02:00 which is fine as per written code. But I want output of format **01-JUN-20**

What formatter shall I use to achieve this? 
Also will 'Europe/London' give proper date while in DST & also while not in DST?
please help me in above 2 questions.

Comment: Have you tried creating a `DateTimeFormatter` with the appropriate format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse/format dates with LocalDateTime? (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8)

Comment: [How to format a ZonedDateTime to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425393/how-to-format-a-zoneddatetime-to-a-string)

Comment: @Savior will try with above links you provided. Thanks for it. Just wanted to check if my code snippet will work both during DST and non DST?

Comment: If you don't want to format as ISO_DATE, why are you using ISO_DATE as your datetime formatter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
.now(
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" )
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu" )
    .withLocale( Locale.UK )
)
.toUpperCase(
    Locale.UK
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/zweMON).

> 01-JUN-20

## Details

You asked:

> will 'Europe/London' give proper date while in DST & also while not in DST?

Yes, your code is correct. Passing a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to [`ZonedDateTime.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now(java.time.ZoneId)) does account for any anomalies in wall-clock time, including the anomaly of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). The result is a date and time-of-day as seen by people in that region when they look up at the calendar & clock on their respective wall.

You may find it interesting or useful to see that same moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Extract a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) object by calling [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant()).

You said:

> But I want output of format 01-JUN-20

Define a custom formatting pattern to match your desired output. Instantiate a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object.

Specify a `Locale` object to determine the human language and cultural norms in naming and abbreviating the month name.

```
Locale locale = Locale.UK ;  // Or Locale.US, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu" ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = myZonedDateTime.format( f ) ;
```

I do not know how to force all-uppercase in a `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern. Perhaps [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) might help; I don't know. As a workaround, you could simply call [`String.toUpperCase( Locale )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase(java.util.Locale)).

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;  // Or Locale.UK, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu" ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = myZonedDateTime.format( f ).toUpperCase( locale ) ;
```

### Tips

- I suggest you not hard-code a format such as that. Generally better to let *java.time* automatically localize for you by calling `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`.
- And I further suggest avoiding the use of only two digits for year as that makes the output harder to read and creates ambiguity. Saving a few pixels or toner particles does not justify the confusion I have seen occur in businesses.
- Consider using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for dates, if your users are amenable: YYYY-MM-DD. This format is easy to recognize, easy to process mentally (large-medium-small level of detail), and easy to read across cultures. The ISO 8601 formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes when generating/parsing text.