# Converting string to 'Instant'

Tags: java, date, timezone, zoneddatetime, java.time.instant

I am trying to convert datetime in a string to an *Instant* instance using Java 8 or a utilities package.

For example,

```
String requestTime = "04:30 PM, Sat 5/12/2018";
```

to

```
Instant reqInstant should result in 2018-05-12T20:30:00.000Z
```

reqString is in the [America/Toronto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#TORONTO) time zone.

This is what I tried

```
 String strReqDelTime = "04:30 PM, Sat 5/12/2018";
 Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a, EEE MM/dd/yyyy").parse(requestTime);
 Instant reqInstant = date.toInstant();
```

The above code results in *"2018-05-12T23:30:00Z"*.

How can I do it?

Comment: you can try to call sdf.setTimeZone("your TZ")

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov I tried that but it gives "2018-05-12T16:30:00Z"

Comment: `Instant` Is not a `String` and not have a `format`, can you describe what you want exactly?

Comment: sorry I edited my question. I am expecting Instant to result in 2018-05-12T20:30:00.000Z for "04:30 PM, Sat 5/12/2018" which in America/Toronto timezone

Comment: @Venky can you try this `Instant instance = LocalDateTime.parse(
        requestTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a, EEE MM/dd/yyyy")
).toInstant(ZoneOffset.of("America/Toronto"));`

Comment: @YCF_L That results in exception
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '04:30 PM, Sat 5/12/2018' could not be parsed at index 14

Comment: No need to mix the modern classes (`Instant`) with the troubled legacy classes (`Date` & `SimpleDateFormat`). Use the *java.time* classes only; they entirely supplant the old ones.

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Edit out your particular variable names, make them `input`, `result` and such to ease our reading. "reqString"??? And clarify exactly what are the inputs, outputs, and unmet expectations.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

### tl;dr

- Fix your formatting pattern for unpadded month and day.
- Use only *java.time* classes, never the legacy classes.

Contrived example:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(                   // Parse as an indeterminate `LocalDate`, devoid of time zone or offset-from-UTC. NOT a moment, NOT a point on the timeline.
    "04:30 PM, Sat 5/12/2018" ,        // This input uses a poor choice of format. Whenever possible, use standard ISO 8601 formats when exchanging date-time values as text. Conveniently, the java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a, EEE M/d/uuuu", Locale.US)  // Use single-character `M` & `d` when the number lacks a leading padded zero for single-digit values.
)                                      // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
.atZone(                               // Apply a zone to that unzoned `LocalDateTime`, giving it meaning, determining a point on the timeline.
    ZoneId.of("America/Toronto")       // Always specify a proper time zone with `Contintent/Region` format, never a 3-4 letter pseudo-zone such as `PST`, `CST`, or `IST`.
)                                      // Returns a `ZonedDateTime`. `toString` → 2018-05-12T16:30-04:00[America/Toronto].
.toInstant()                           // Extract a `Instant` object, always in UTC by definition.
.toString()                            // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format representing the value within this `Instant` object. Note that this string is *generated*, not *contained*.
```

> 2018-05-12T20:30:00Z

### Use single-digit formatting pattern

You used `MM` in your formatting pattern, to mean any single-digit value (months January-September) will appear with a padded leading zero.

But your input lacks that padded leading zero. So use a single `M`.

Ditto for day-of-month I expect: `d` rather than `dd`.

### Use only *java.time*

You are using troublesome flawed old date-time classes (`Date` & `SimpleDateFormat`) that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. The new classes entirely supplant the old. There isn't any need to mix the legacy and modern.

### `LocalDateTime`

Parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) because your input string lacks any indicator of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). Such a value is *not* a moment, and it is *not* a point on the timeline. It is only a set of *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours.

```
String input = "04:30 PM, Sat 5/12/2018";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a, EEE M/d/uuuu", Locale.US);  // Specify locale to determine human language and cultural norms used in translating that input string.
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, f);
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-05-12T16:30

#### `ZonedDateTime`

If you know for certain that input was intended to represent a moment using the wall-clock time used by the people of the Toronto Canada region, apply a `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

Assigning a time zone gives meaning to your unzoned `LocalDateTime`. Now we have a moment, a point on the timeline.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("America/Toronto");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(z);  // Give meaning to that `LocalDateTime` by assigning the context of a particular time zone. Now we have a moment, a point on the timeline.
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-05-12T16:30-04:00[America/Toronto]

#### `Instant`

To see that same moment as [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

> instant.toString(): 2018-05-12T20:30:00Z

---

### About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. There isn't any need for strings or for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where can we obtain the *java.time* classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for to the point explanation!! that solves my problem.

Comment: Very extensive and good answer, thank you very much! Could you comment on the use of the Locale in `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a, EEE M/d/uuuu" , Locale.US )`, please? The doc says that "The locale affects some aspects of formatting and parsing. For example, the `ofLocalizedDate` provides a formatter that uses the locale specific date format." I don't really get how it affects parsing as the parsing is determined by the provided pattern...? How does a change to the locale (implicitly) affect the prescribed parsing pattern?

Comment: @JanusVarmarken The `Locale` determines the human language and cultural norms used in localizing, for translating the name of the day of the week, for example, and for deciding issues such as commas versus periods, capitalization, abbreviations, order of elements, and so on.

Comment: There is a problem with LocalDateTime.parse() - if your pattern doesn't contain time, parse() will throw an exception, so you have to add two try blocks like (pseudocode):
fun parse(): Instant? = try { LocalDateTime.parse() } catch { try { LocalDate.parse() } catch { null } }

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the time zone on your computer (server) is US Pacific DST ([PDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone), GMT-7), but you expect to have the result for US Eastern DST ([EDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone), GMT-4).

Instant.toString() returns UTC (GMT+0) DateTime in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. ('Z' at the end means UTC).

SimpleDateFormat treats DateTime String in the default time zone of the computer when it is not specified. And your input does not specify a time zone.

So, you need to do something about in what time zone your input is.

PS.: On my machine in [Eastern DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone), your code gives me the result exactly as you expected.

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

### What went wrong in your attempt?

The `SimpleDateFormat` uses the system's time-zone by default while you have mentioned that `requestTime` is in ***America/Toronto*** timezone. You should never rely on the default time-zone because when your code will be run on a machine in different time-zone your application may behave in an unexpected manner.

### How should you have done it?

Set the time-zone to America/Toronto before parsing. Also, [Never use Date-Time formatting/parsing API without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

**Demo**:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String requestTime = "04:30 PM, Sat 5/12/2018";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a, EEE MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Toronto"));
        Date date = sdf.parse(requestTime);
        Instant reqInstant = date.toInstant();
        System.out.println(reqInstant);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2018-05-12T20:30:00Z
```

### Do not pollute the clean java.time API with the error-prone java.util API

The java.time API introduced with Java-8 (March 2014) supplants the error-prone and outdated `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`. It is recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). You tried parsing the date-time string using the legacy API and then switching to the modern API using [`Date#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) while you could have done everything using the modern API.

You should use [`Date#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) to switch to the modern API if you are using an old code/library that uses `java.util.Date`.

### Solution using the modern date-time API

Parse the date-time string to `LocalDateTime` as it does not have time-zone → Convert the obtained `LocalDateTime` into `ZonedDateTime` of the given time-zone → Convert the obtained `ZonedDateTime` into `Instant`.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String requestTime = "04:30 PM, Sat 5/12/2018";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:m a, EEE M/d/u", Locale.ENGLISH);

        // Parse the date-time string to LocalDateTime as it does not have time-zone
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(requestTime, dtf);

        // Convert the LocalDateTime into ZonedDateTime of the given time-zone
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Toronto"));

        // Convert the ZonedDateTime into Instant
        Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2018-05-12T20:30:00Z
```

Note that I [prefer u to y](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) with `DateTimeFormatter`.

### An alternative solution using the modern date-time API

You can convert the obtained `LocalDateTime` directly into an `Instant` using [`LocalDateTime#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#toInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-) by supplying it with the time-zone ID.

```
Instant instant = ldt.toInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Toronto").getRules().getOffset(ldt));
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

For the description, you can read *[Convert String to Date in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-to-date)*.

```
String requestTime = "04:30 PM, Sat 5/12/2018 America/Toronto";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a, EEE M/dd/yyyy z");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(requestTime, formatter);
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
```

Comment: It works correctly on my Java 17 when running in an English-speaking locale. For it to work in other locales, we need to specify locale in the formatter. In any case it’s much better than your previous (now deleted) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instant.parse(String) appropriately formatted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please tell us what 'appropriately formatted' means, this answer is close to useless.

Comment: The most useful answer among others. It could be used like that: `Instant.parse("2023-12-15T14:16:43.12Z");`. Standard ISO-8601 format, check .parse() method Javadoc for more details