# Can't change Calendar DAY_OF_MONTH in Java

Tags: java, date, calendar, dayofmonth

I have a little issue in Java Calendar setting. The problem is I have this code and it returns `"1980.09.12."`.

I can change the year and month to whatever I want, but can't change the day.

```
public class printableBeosztas extends HttpServlet {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.");
    Calendar calHetfo;

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        setDates();
        response.getWriter().append(sdf.format(calHetfo.getTime());
    }

    public void setDates() {
        calHetfo = Calendar.getInstance();
        calHetfo.set(Calendar.MONTH, 8);
        calHetfo.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1980);
        calHetfo.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I have used the setDates() it works as expected. Where you have been using this? And how you used SimpleDateFormat in your code?

Comment: It is a servlet i want to use to list all the shift data from a date to a date. It is usually from monday to friday and i generate the other date from this calHetfo with day_of_week. Everything is working fine except this day_of_month. I use sdf just to transform Calendar to dateformat.

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be more easier if you are using [**java.time**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API of Java 8+, where you can use [`LocalDate.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-java.time.Month-int-) and set whatever you want :

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(1980, Month.SEPTEMBER, 12);
```

To format the date you can use :

```
String format = ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd."));
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But still don't know why my code didn't work

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code did it gives you an error?

Comment: No error, just not the expected result. I could change everything except the day

Comment: I try your code and it work fine with me check the [idone demo](https://ideone.com/Z2iDC4)

Comment: Thanks, I checked. But believe me, it didn't work (used  the same technic somewhere else with success), and i couldn't figure out why... Thanks your time, effort and solution!

Comment: You are welcome @Andor we are here to help each other ;)

Comment: @Andor Whatever the mysterious cause of your issue, it is moot as those old date-time classes really are a wretched mess that should be avoided. Best to forget about them, not waste anymore time trying to figure them out, and move on. The *java.time* classes replace them entirely, incl `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, `java.sql.Timestamp`, `java.sql.Date`, etc. As of Java 8 and JDBC 4.2, there is no need to ever touch the legacy classes again. For interfacing with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back-and-forth via new conversion methods added to the old classes.

Comment: @Andor - *Thanks, it's working. But still don't know why my code didn't work*. -It may be because of `Locale`. [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).