# How to parse time in any format with LocalTime.parse?

Tags: java, time, localtime, datetime-parsing, time-format

I am having trouble using java's `LocalTime` to parse a string with hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
LocalTime t = LocalTime.parse("8:30:17"); // Simplification
```

This throws the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text '8:30:17' could not be parsed at index 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to pass in a custom `DateTimeFormatter` like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss");
LocalTime t = LocalTime.parse(times.get(i), formatter);
```

Take a look at [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), as the letters you need to use might be different.

Answer (score 6):

The default formatter expects an ISO format, which uses 2 digits for each of the hours, minutes and seconds.

If you want to parse the time you showed, which only has one digit for hours, you will need to provide a custom formatter (note the single `H`):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss");
LocalTime t = LocalTime.parse(times.get(i), formatter);
```

Comment: Won't this break when it is, say, 10 o'clock?

Comment: No it won't (see the javadoc: "*If the count of letters is one, then the value is output using the minimum number of digits and without padding.*").

Comment: Just tested it. Hey @Yuri, make this the accepted answer again, it's the correct one.

Comment: It’s a bit funny but very useful, @Schred: For numbers (including hour of day) one pattern letter does not mean one digit but rather *as many digits as it takes*. So it will parse `8`, `08` and `10` happily. And print `8` or `10` (never `08`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DateTimeFormatter` to give parser a format pattern to parse.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss");
LocalTime t = LocalTime.parse(times.get(i), formatter);
```

Format Pattern Letters:

```
H       hour-of-day (0-23)
m       minute-of-hour
s       second-of-minute            
h       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)
```

Comment: @OleV.V. The interesting part is it the answer is accepted when it is  `HH:mm:ss` this format. Check the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

From [`LocalTime.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) documentation :

> The string must represent a valid time and is parsed using
> DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME.

According to the [`ISO_LOCAL_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME) documentation the condition for the hours is this:

> Two digits for the hour-of-day. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure
> two digits.

You are parsing the value `8:30:17`, one digit instead of two digits and so you are breaking the condition, causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

By default, [`LocalTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) parses the input string using [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME) whose format consists of:

> - Two digits for the hour-of-day. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
> - A colon
> - Two digits for the minute-of-hour. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
> - If the second-of-minute is not available then the format is complete.
> - A colon
> - Two digits for the second-of-minute. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
> - If the nano-of-second is zero or not available then the format is complete.
> - A decimal point
> - One to nine digits for the nano-of-second. As many digits will be output as required.

Since your input string is not in this format, you have encountered the exception. You can get around the exception by using a `DateTimeFormatter` which allows you to specify a custom format. You can use `H:m:s` as the format.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalTime t = LocalTime.parse("8:30:17", dtf);
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
08:30:17
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/1fa80l)

Note that for formatting, the single letter, `H` works for single as well as a two-digit hour. Similar is the case with `m` and `s` as well.

Another thing you should always keep in mind is that the Date-Time formatting types are `Locale`-sensitive and therefore you should always specify the applicable `Locale` when using them. Check [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) to learn more about it.

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>