# Parsing Timezone String Date into Java's Instant

Tags: java, java-time

I'm reading a from a few RSS sites which **don't** send the typical:

- iso representation

  - `2019-06-12T07:17:47Z` - `Instant.parse()` can be used
- RFC1123

  - `Wed, 12 Jun 2019 03:17:47 -0400` - `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.parse()` can be used

Instead I'm getting these strings:

- `Tue, 25 May 2021 00:00:00 EDT`
- `03 Jun 2021 18:35:00 HKT`

I've already tried around with some custom patterns and the ZonedDateTime + OffsetDateTime `parse()` method. Although I haven't found a way to get a date time representation that I can convert into `Instant`. Neither do I control the source and can fix the output format.

How can I be more lenient and parse these date times?

Comment: `Tue, 25 May 2021 00:00:00 EDT` really conforms to RFC 1123 too. Only unfortunately Java’s implementation is limited: *North American zone names … are not handled.* ([Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME))

Comment: @OleV.V. Alternative: My lib [Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.html#RFC_1123) handles North American zone names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `DateTimeFormatter` with a custom pattern that has an optional *day-of-week* at the beginning. Afterwards, use the `parse` method of formatter with which you can specify the desired type of the parsed date-time directly (as per comment of *Ole V.V.*). Another approach is to first parse as `ZonedDateTime` and then convert to an `Instant`.

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[EEE, ]dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);

String input1 = "Tue, 25 May 2021 00:00:00 EDT";
Instant instant1 = formatter.parse(input1, Instant::from);
// Instant instant1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(input1, formatter).toInstant();
System.out.println(instant1);

String input2 = "03 Jun 2021 18:35:00 HKT";
Instant instant2 = formatter.parse(input2, Instant::from);
// Instant instant2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(input2, formatter).toInstant();
System.out.println(instant2);
```

*Output:*

```
2021-05-25T04:00:00Z
2021-06-03T10:35:00Z
```

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Comment: Good answer. Possible alternative: `Instant instant1 = formatter.parse(input1, Instant::from);` (same for `input2`). Feels a bit simpler to me, but it’s a matter of taste. Nice and clever use of optional part for the day of week (the square brackets)!

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for sharing your alternative which I personally find better since no additional conversion from `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant` is necessary. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Matt thanks a lot. Learned also about []. I've extended it to: `[EEE, ]dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz[Z]` to be able to also parse dates such as `Mon, 22 Mar 2021 18:39:18 GMT+0100`. Thanks a lot!