# Default locale in joda time vs. java time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, java-time

I have recently changed from `org.joda.time` package to
`java.time` package and I am wondering how the two differ
in using a default locale.
Locale is used when parsing dates;
the `java.time` seems to use the system language and country as the default
locale while the
`joda.time` uses null,
which I can see using

```
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.getLocale
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.fullDateTime().getLocale
```

```
en_US
null
```

The Joda documentation on the getLocale() states

```
    /**
     * Gets the locale that will be used for printing and parsing.
     * 
     * @return the locale to use; if null, formatter uses default locale at
     * invocation time
     */
    public Locale getLocale() {
        return iLocale;
    }
```

Which says it's using the default locale at invocation time.
Is this default always English "en"?
If I change the language on my system,
java time wont parse English dates,
while Joda time still accepts it.

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you say about Joda-Time accepting dates in English when the system language is different. On my Danish Mac a Joda-Time `DateTimeFormat.longDate()` parses `19. juni 2021` but throws an exception for the English counterpart: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "June 19, 2021"`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, No.

The Jvm uses its own locale which is dependent on the underlying system locale configuration if you want to have a stable default locale configuration you should provide the jvm the arguments related to the [locale](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/locale.html#using) user.country user.variant, user.variant. It is important also to provide user.timezone

Answer (score 0):

You should not care. Instead specify desired locale for your parsing and formatting explicitly. If you want the default locale of the JVM to be used, specify `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)`.

```
    DateTimeFormatter germanFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG)
            .withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
    DateTimeFormatter frenchFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG)
            .withLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
    
    LocalDate sample = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.OCTOBER, 23);
    
    System.out.println(sample.format(germanFormatter));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("31. März 2022", germanFormatter));
    
    System.out.println(sample.format(frenchFormatter));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("30 août 2021", frenchFormatter));
```

Output:

> ```
> 23. Oktober 2021
> 2022-03-31
> 23 octobre 2021
> 2021-08-30
> ```