# How to parse date string '2021-08-03T10:00:00EDT' to ZonedDateTime in java?

Tags: java, string, date, zoneddatetime, datetimeformatter

I am getting below error when trying with pattern with below pattern

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");
```

Can someone explain reason behind this??

**Error received with above pattern:**
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-08-03T10:00:00EDT' could not be parsed at index 19

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Also, what's your current `Locale`?

Comment: [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27479533/4718933)

Comment: On my computer this works for both Locales of 'en_US' and 'hi_IN'.  19 puts you at the 'E'.  Wonder if your Java installation does not know about EDT, which is Eastern Daylight Time.

Comment: This code snippet might help.  It did not print 'EDT' specifically but did print variations.    
    for (String t : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {System.out.println(t);}

Comment: A [mre], please? Also asking because I cannot reproduce either. I am parsing your string without any signs of problems.

Comment: Your string is funny. It’s trying to be [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) but the trailing `EDT` disagrees with ISO 8601 (ISO 8601 would be like `2021-08-03T10:00-04:00`). You will probably prefer if you can get a real ISO 8601 string.

Comment: Could there be a funny non-printing character between the last `00` and `EDT`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text could not be parsed, unparsed text found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335396/text-could-not-be-parsed-unparsed-text-found)

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock We din’t know whether it’s supposed to mean Australian or North American/Caribbean Eastern Daylight Time. Neither does Java, so if we get a result, we don’t know which one. Parsing time zone abbreviations is a non-deterministic business.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse by following way

```
String val="2021-08-03T10:00:00EDT";
DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime=ZonedDateTime.parse(val,DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
```