# Java YearMonth will not parse, but only on my computer?

Tags: java, parsing, java-11, java-time

I have been working on a project that requires me to parse a string in this manner
i have seperated out the small part that has been throwing errors,

```
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TestingYearMonth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
           YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse("Feb-17", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-yy"));
            System.out.println(yearMonth.getMonth() + " " + yearMonth.getYear());
        
    }
}
```

my teacher runs the exact same code and it returns an output no problem. but when i run it i get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Feb-17' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.YearMonth.parse(YearMonth.java:295)
    at com.ethanbradley.assignment6.TestingYearMonth.main(TestingYearMonth.java:10)
```

we checked and my jdk is fine (jdk 11, the amazon coretto version)
i really cannot see why this does not work, please help oh wise internet people....

Comment: What is the `Locale` of your machine?

Comment: Try `.ofPattern("MMM-yy", Locale.US)`

Comment: Wow, adding Locale.US works but no other Locale seems to, do you know why?

Comment: @EthanLTB Different locales have different requirements on how the month value is generated/parsed, some might be `FEB` for example (excluding non English languages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Specify a `Locale`

Likely that the default locale of your JVM is not one that recognizes “Feb” as month of February.

Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms to be used in parsing the name of month.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM-yy" , locale ) ;
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse( "Feb-17" , f );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DUxZFM).

## ISO 8601

Using localized text for data-exchange is unwise. I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats for exchanging date-time values as text.

The standard format for year-month is YYYY-MM. Example: `2017-02`.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default.

```
YearMonth.parse( "2017-02" )
```

Comment: (1) The note about ISO 8601 is nice and important. (2) I would prefer `u` to `y`. (3) To the OP: You can learn more about the importance of `Locale` with `DateTimeFormatter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Comment: That's great Thanks!

Comment: You have succeeded. :-)