# java Unparseable date "yyyy MMM d HH:mm:ss"

Tags: java, date, exception, formatter

I am a beginner and i want to convert this String into a Date Instance. Why get i an unparsable Exception ? Can anyone help me ?

```
String s=  "2020 Mar 11 11:09:42";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM d HH:mm:ss");
Date parsedDate =  formatter.parse(s);
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @celikler_data there is nothing wrong with your code. I just executed it since I didn't see any errors in it. It works just fine. What error do you get, exactly? Maybe the message that there is a possible exception you don't throw or catch?

Comment: @Stultuske There is something wrong with the code. It does not specify the locale to be used for parsing. Not all languages have a month that is abbreviated `Mar`.

Comment: i get this error message: Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020 Mar 11 11:09:42"

Comment: @celikler_data Ole is on to something. What language is your system in?

Comment: We mean, the default language of your JVM, is it English, Turkish or something else? (It probably picks up a default language from the OS, not guaranteed.)

Comment: my system language is german..

Comment: Thank you so much it works now i changed the month

Comment: the reason of the error was the system language :))

Comment: I still recommend that you switch to java.time. Use `LocalDateTime parsedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u MMM d HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH));` (still remembering to specify locale). It yields `2020-03-11T11:09:42`.

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).