# How can I parse ~german custom formatted dates in java?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I want to parse to `LocalDate` the dates I receive in a format like this but with german months:

- 15-Aug-2023
- 30-Mai-2024
- 13-Okt-2021
- 31-Mrz-2034
- 02-Dez-2013

I simplified the code that should parse these formatted dates (months are in german) but still it doesnt' work on jdk 11.0.7 and openjdk 11.0.13

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String txt = "15-Aug-2023";
        DateTimeFormatter format =  new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                .toFormatter(Locale.GERMAN);
        LocalDate.parse(txt, format);
    }
```

throws exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
> Text '15-Aug-2023' could not be parsed at index 3

What am I missing?

PS just noticed that if I do:

```
System.out.println(format.format(LocalDate.now()));
```

I get:

> 24-Okt.-2023

How can I overcome this unexpected dot?

Comment: "15-Aug-2023" is the same date in German and English (August is August).

Comment: yeah I know thats why i chose it and still doesn't work :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69860992/when-i-format-a-localdate-to-dd-mmm-yyyy-i-get-01-jan-2000-with-two-dots this question is about formatting, but I guess the solution applies to parsing as well. TLDR: `Locale.GERMAN` requires the dots; you have to use a custom locale or overwrite the month abbreviations.

Comment: "Mrz" is a non-standard abbreviation. The standard abbreviation for month "März" is "Mär".

Comment: Suggestion: Educate the publisher of your data about exchanging date-time values as text using [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats only rather than localized text.

Answer (score 2):

This runs for me:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String txt = "15-Aug-2023";
        DateTimeFormatter format =  new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("dd-LLL-yyyy")
                .toFormatter(Locale.GERMAN);
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(txt, format));
    }
}
```

Prints: 2023-08-15

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: The JavaDoc could be improved on this one. It's quite unclear what M does vs what L does (and why one gives a dot and the other doesn't)

Comment: `System.out.println(format.format(LocalDate.now()));` prints `24-Okt-2023`here. Ok, having openjdk version "21" 2023-09-19

Comment: Yes, I get that. The official JavaDoc should still be improved. This answer is fine.

Comment: Still is not working for 31-Mrz-2034 same error. I dont't know how are they sending these dates !???

Comment: @MS13 because "Mrz" is not the "correct" (official?) abbreviation. It is "Mär". If you make up non-standard abbreviations, you must use a custom locale (or custom month-mapping; see linked q&a under the question)