# Android Unparseable date exception when try to parse date format

Tags: java, android, kotlin, date-parsing

I try to parse this date "Wed Jul 12 2023 23:58:20 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"
using this code

```
  val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss ", Locale.getDefault())
    val time = try {
        val mDate = sdf.parse(input)
        mDate!!.time
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        -1
    }
```

But I get this error

> Unparseable date: "Wed Jul 12 2023 23:58:20 GMT+0000 (Coordinated
> Universal Time)"

Comment: @Unmitigated You are right this only happens if the localization changed.
on my case the function works fine in English but when the app turns to Arabic here I faced the issue , I Changed Locale.getDefault() to Locale.ENGLISH and the problem solved

Comment: [Never use `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573). Also, I recommend you switch from the error-prone legacy date-time API to the modern date-time API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only happens if the localization changed.
on my case the function works fine in English but when the app turns to Arabic here I faced the issue ,

> I Changed **Locale.getDefault()** to **Locale.ENGLISH** and the problem solved