# How to parse a date string containing a numerical zone offset

Tags: java, date-format, java-time

I have this date in string `"Fri, 14 Jul 2023 11:53:06 -0400"`

and I am unable to convert it in LocalDateTime
I have tried this pattern "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z" and I have date format exception

any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: the patterns are listed in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) (with examples and explanation about how many symbols are needed)

Comment: [Never use `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` without a `Locale`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Answer (score 4):

The [Answer by bhspencer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76757486/642706) identifies part of the problem, needing a tweak to your formatting pattern. However, you may also need to specify a `Locale` with your `DateTimeFormatter`.

But FYI, there is a simpler approach. No need to specify a formatting pattern at all.

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( 
    "Fri, 14 Jul 2023 11:53:06 -0400" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME 
)
```

## RFC 1123 / RFC 822

Your input string `"Fri, 14 Jul 2023 11:53:06 -0400"` complies with the outdated standard format defined in [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) & RFC 822.

*java.time* comes with a formatter predefined for that format. See class [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).

```java
String input = "Fri, 14 Jul 2023 11:53:06 -0400" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME );
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ZTIFF0).

> odt.toString() = 2023-07-14T11:53:06-04:00

---

Tip: Educate the publisher of your data about using the modern [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats rather than these troublesome outmoded formats.

And educate them on using a fully-formed offset, including the optional COLON. I have seen multiple protocols and libraries that do not tolerate the omitted COLON. And easier to read by humans if included.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the zone offset. You are using a lowercase 'z' which is for a named time zone e.g. "PST" or "EST". Try with a capital 'Z' as shown below for a numerical zone offset:

```
    String date = "Fri, 14 Jul 2023 11:53:06 -0400";
    String pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"; //Note the capital 'Z'
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
```

Comment: still getting DateTimeParseException

Comment: @akaliza are you using a different date or pattern string. The above code compiles and parses the date from your question correctly.

Comment: the same code I am getting the error in intelliJ, but in replit it works , I am using java 18, maybe i should reference the ZoneId ?

Comment: ok, adding local to date formatter solves the issue, thank you everyone

Comment: It says _"... could not be parsed at index 0"_, so it doesn't understand _"Fri"_.

Answer (score 0):

With below code I am able to get result without error in date format. Not sure if this is what you needed. Or comment here and will explore options.

**Code**

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E, d LLL u HH:mm:ss Z");
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("Fri, 14 Jul 2023 11:53:06 -0400", fmt);
System.out.println(date);
```

**Result**

```
2023-07-14T11:53:06
```

Answer (score -1):

*Updated with code*

You have to combine a couple of things:

1. Parse the date into an `OffsetDateTime` (which has the timezone part)
2. Convert that into an `Instant` which like an "absolute" time.
3. Get your local offset, so you see what that would be in your local time
4. Convert the instant into `LocalDateTime` using that offset.

Code

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;


/* 1 */ var odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("Fri, 14 Jul 2023 11:53:06 -0400",
                               DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
/* 2 */ var instant = odt.toInstant();
/* 3 */ var localOffset = OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset();
/* 4 */ var result = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, localOffset);


/*
Result
odt ==> 2023-07-14T11:53:06-04:00
instant ==> 2023-07-14T15:53:06Z
localOffset ==> -05:00
result ==> 2023-07-14T10:53:06
*/
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34739497)

Comment: Removed link to docs and added some code