# Java DateTimeFormatter expression to parse "Wed Jun 03 12:00:00 PM GMT 2020"

Tags: java, date-formatting, datetimeformatter

I am using an application written in Java, that uses LocalDate.parse with a DateTimeFormatter:

```
LocalDate.parse("Wed Jun 03 12:00:00 PM GMT 2020", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss a zzz yyyy"));
```

I can only provide the format string (I cannot modify the source code). I need it to successfully parse a somewhat crazy date format that looks like this:

```
Wed Jun 03 12:00:00 PM GMT 2020
```

The closest format I've gotten to is:

```
EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss a zzz yyyy
```

but this bombs out with

```
Exception java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed Jun 03 12:00:00 PM GMT 2020' could not be parsed at index 20
```

If I remove the AM/PM in the date and format, all works fine. Any tweaks that will make this parse successfully?

Comment: AM/PM are locale-sensitive, so make sure you set the locale to one that actually uses "AM" and "PM". That said, this might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It is rare that you need to parse a format like this that is meant to be human-readable.

Comment: What other values can the "GMT" part be? Is this an offset name, time zone abbreviation, or time zone name? Is any of the parts in the string localised depending on locale? Or are they always in the same locale?

Comment: @Sweeper locale is en_GB - that string will actually always be GMT, and in fact always midnight as far as I can tell! Which actually just gave me an idea - I may be able to get away with using a literal, thanks!

EEE MMM dd '12:00:00 PM GMT' yyyy

Comment: There is no error when using _LocalDate.parse(s, f)_.  What is the code, that is being used? _DateTimeFormatterBuilder_?

Comment: @Relias

LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatPattern))

Comment: @JamesCrowley, I get "2020-06-03".  I'm using _Java 20, build 20+36-2344_.

Comment: Your date-time string also has alphabets which are `Locale`-dependent. Check [Always specify a Locale with a SimpleDateFormat, and a DateTimeFormatter for custom formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) to learn more about it. If you are allowed to use a `Locale`, try `LocalDate.parse("Wed Jun 03 12:00:00 PM GMT 2020", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss a z uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH))`.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse( 
    "Wed Jun 03 12:00:00 PM GMT 2020" , 
    DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss a z uuuu" )
        .withLocale( Locale.US )
)
.toInstant()
.toString()
```

> 2020-06-03T12:00Z

### `ZonedDateTime`, not `LocalDate`

[`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) is the wrong class for your input. A `LocalDate` has only a date, no time-of-day, and no time zone.

You should be using [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class.

### Specify locale for localization rules

Define a custom format matching your output using the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

Specify a `Locale`. Your input is localized in multiple ways: Name of day of week, name of month, and AM/PM. Choose a `Locale` that represents the localization choices seen in your inputs. I believe `Locale.US` might work.

```java
String input = "Wed Jun 03 12:00:00 PM GMT 2020" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss a z uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> zdt.toString() = 2020-06-03T12:00Z[GMT]

## `LocalDate`

If you *really* want only the date portion, and wish to discard the time-of-day and offset/zone, then parse as a `LocalDate` while using the same correct formatting pattern.

```java
LocalDate ld = 
    LocalDate.parse( 
        "Wed Jun 03 12:00:00 PM GMT 2020" , 
        DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss a z uuuu" )
            .withLocale( Locale.US )
    );
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/3turpl). Be aware that the date extracted is the date as seen in the parsed time zone.

> ld.toString() = 2020-06-03

### ISO 8601

The ideal solution is educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for communicating date-time values unambiguously as text.

Your example input should have been sent as: 2020-06-03T12:00Z

The `Z` on the end is an abbreviation of `+00:00`, pronounced “Zulu”, and means an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds ahead of the temporal meridian of UTC.

Comment: Thanks @Basil - unfortunately as noted in the question - I am unable to modify the source code of the application, or the web app serving the crazy date, hence being stuck with their implementation and just trying to figure out a format string that works. It seems to be a potential bug though, given it works if I remove the PM/AM element from the equation.

Comment: @JamesCrowley As Basil explained, a `LocalDate` doesn't have a time zone.  In fact, it doesn't have a time at all.  So no matter what format string you use, you're not going to be able to parse the time or the time zone correctly with this code.  You need to use `ZonedDateTime` instead of `LocalDate`.  You will HAVE to modify the source code, whether your employer likes it or not.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Your Comment prompted me to rethink the problem. I had assumed that parsing as `ZonedDateTime` was required. But it is *not* required. That input string with date, time, and pseudo-zone components *can* be parsed as a `LocalDate`. See new section of my Answer. Using the same formatting pattern works with both `ZonedDateTime.parse` and `LocalDate.parse`.